# Adding a trailing slash to a URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using .htaccess

I would like to rewrite all url requests similar to below:

http://myhomework.ca/courses/math-9/2-2

so that they redirect to include a trailing slash:

http://myhomework.ca/courses/math-9/2-2/

Tried a lot of the examples on the web but cannot find a working solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think its help to you.

```
RewriteRule ^courses/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/(0-9-]+)/?$ filename.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you should provide current rules or what you've tried. This should work for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```